# Assigning string array to char**

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I just cannot assign string array to my char** pointer.

I have my strings in `char *tempArr[12];`

But I don't know how to assign them to my char** arr variable.

First, I allocate memory using: `arr = (char**)malloc(numberOfElements * sizeof(char*));`

Then I tried to allocate memory to each element:

```
arr[i] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
```

I also tried to alocate just the memory for char pointer but neither works. The result in my arr variable is 2 to 3 nonsense characters.

What could be wrong? I tried everything I was able to find and the result is either crash or nonsense content.

EDIT: Sorry I'll try to clarify it more. Background is, I am loading data from file into structs. Each struct has `char**` variable that is suppose to hold strings array.

In my reading code, I am using my temp array `char* tempArr[12]` and successfully loading strings into it. Then I pass it allong to my function that is creating my structs.

The problem starts here, I was trying to "convert" my passed array so it can be stored in `char** arr` variable.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There are too many things missing in this question to provide an accurate answer with wagging (wild-ass-guessing). Your `arr = ...` makes sense (more-so if you lose the cast, which for some odd reason you did incorrectly there, but correctly in your `arr[i] = ...` assignment). If this is *entirely* self-contained in some function scope, it looks right. If `char **arr` is a function out-parameter, then its wrong. [**Post an MCVE of the REAL problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *tempArr[12];
```

Is array of pointers. So if you have something like

```
tempArr[0] = malloc(20);
strcpy(tempArr[0],"hello");
```

Then after what you are doing you can do. i.e. After allocating memory to your the pointer `arr[i]`

```
char **arr = malloc(numberOfElements * sizeof(char*));

arr[i] = malloc(256);

strcpy(arr[i],tempArr[0]);
```

You can run the above steps in a loop to copy values for all your pointers

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks. My problem was in the for cycle (I counted number of elements and didn't factor in that array starts at zero) so while I was trying this before I thought it doesn't work when in fact problem was elsewhere :/

Answer (score 2):

I think that you mean the following

```
#include <string.h>

//...

size_t i;

char **arr = ( char** )malloc( numberOfElements * sizeof( char* ) );
for ( i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++ ) arr[i] = malloc( 256 * sizeof( char ) );

for ( i = 0; i < sizeof( tempArr ) / sizeof( *tempArr ); i++ ) strcpy( arr[i], tempArr[i] );
```